# Assigning by reference fails with syntax error

Tags: php, reference

I have a class instance `$obj = new class`. `obj` is actually a variable from another object so it's more like `$obj1->obj2->obj3 = new class`. This is making my code a little confusing so I want to do something like:

`$var =& $obj1->obj2->obj3 = new class`

and then start using this instance as

`$var->method()` or `$var->name = 'abc'`.

When using it like `$var = $obj1->obj2->obj3 = new class` it works just fine but I was thinking about the memory I could save (as the object is quite large and duplicating it would not be advisable). I'm not sure if this is an issue or if it actually necessary to assign by reference or if PHP takes this into consideration.

I forgot to mention, using `$var =& $obj1->obj2->obj3 = new class` results in:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '='

Comment: Could you clarify your question please?

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Going with the method I'd _like_ to do throws an error. Plus I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing what I want to achieve. Thanks!

Comment: @Wiseguy I'm not sure about that.  `$var &= $x` is equivalent to `$var = $var & $x`, which is not quite the same thing.

Comment: You're looking for `$var = &$x`.  But as the accepted answer states, you don't need the variable reference since you have an object reference already...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
$var = new stdClass();
$var2 = $var;
```

`$var2` is actually a reference to `$var`. This is because PHP passes classes by reference. So you aren't actually making a new copy. So you can assign it to your shorter variable and reduce the typing.

Answer (score 2):

Doing the following will assign the same object to `$obj1->obj2->obj3` and `$var`.

```
$obj1->obj2->obj3 = new class;
$var = $obj1->obj2->obj3;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really! (I accepted JohnP's answer because he was quicker but I do realize you were both typing at the same time. :) ).

Answer (score 1):

- As of PHP 5, objects are always passed by reference. In PHP 4 `$a = new obj;` would in fact duplicate the object, once during creation, and another during assignment to `$a`, this is no longer the case.
- Regular variables in PHP are copy on write, so even `$a = 'fred'; $b = $a;` hasn't doubled the memory usage (yet)
- In general with PHP, until you run into problems it's best to just let the language do the work, rather than trying to out-think it :)

Answer (score 0):

Fields initialization should be done in constructor or another class method.

You can do initialization like usual (it's one time)

```
$this->obj2->obj3 = new Class();
```

After that in the outer code you can do

```
$var = $obj1->obj2->obj3;
$var->method;
```

Also please note, using nested objects complicates the system and too deep nesting is not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question about the syntax error, the reason you're getting a syntax error is because you're trying to assign a reference to something that's not a variable.

This code:

```
$var =& $obj1->obj2->obj3 = new class
```

gets evaluated like this ([because the = operator has right associativity](http://php.net/language.operators.precedence)):

```
$var =& ($obj1->obj2->obj3 = new class)
```

which doesn't work because you can't create a reference to an expression.

As far as creating a reference to the object rather than a copy, that depends on which version of PHP you're running.  In PHP5, [objects are (effectively) always passed by reference](http://php.net/language.oop5.references).

Comment: Thanks for clearing this out. So it's safe to say `$var = $obj1->obj2 = new class` is the right method or should I break it into two separate assignments?

Comment: Getting rid of the '&' altogether would demonstrate a better understanding of how the language works and stave off condescending looks during a code review, but either of the two would work (:

Comment: Thanks! I'm not using the `&` anymore.